# How to resolve build error: Unable to copy file. Access to the path is denied

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The full error is this:

Error       Unable to copy file "C:\TFS.WorkSpace\Argosy\Argosy\Base\Interop\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll" to "..\ArgosyBuild\Interop\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll". Access to the path '..\ArgosyBuild\Interop\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll' is denied.

About 20 developers are working on a same TFS based solution and I'm the only one with this recurring problem.

Things I've tried are cleaning solution and deleting entire folder and downloading again with no effect. The only thing that works is selecting build folder and removing the read only flag from files. But, this solution only works one time. Next build will return some of the flags every time.

We have about 30 referenced dll's in our solution. Those dll's are with the solution and not in GAC and their build action is set to: Copy always. I always get about 2-7 dll's with this error randomly chosen.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated ...

> The only thing that works is selecting build folder and removing the
>   read only flag from files.

Have you tried to change the read only flag on the folder that holds these files?

Comment: I'll try it. But, Visual studio and TFS don't usually like it when you change read only flags on source controlled files.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the "clean" option by right clicking on the project